# merb callbacks equivalent in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merb

Is there **rails** equivalents for :

```
Merb::BootLoader.after_app_loads
Merb::BootLoader.before_app_loads

Merb::Assets::JavascriptAssetBundler.add_callback
Merb::Assets::StylesheetAssetBundler.add_callback
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- before_app_loads:  i guess [preinitializer.rb](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-a-preinitializer) is what you are after.
- after_app_loads: is this [how to use an after-initializer callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-an-after-initializer)

About the other, i am not sure.